# Javascript: How to append <textarea> rows

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `<textarea>` that I am attempting to add quotation marks around each value a user puts inside the text box upon clicking a button. My code appears to be viewing every row as 1 large value and just adds quotation marks at the beginning of the first word and end of the last word where it looks like this:

```
"one word
two word
three word"
```

I am attempting to achieve this output:

```
"one word"
"two word"
"three word"
```

Here's my current code:

```js
document.getElementById("phraseButton").addEventListener('click', function () {
  var keywordBox = document.getElementById('keywordBox');
   keywordBox.value = ('"' + keywordBox.value + '"'); 
});
```

```html
<textarea id="keywordBox" type="text" rows="100" cols="30">Insert Keywords</textarea>
<button id="phraseButton">Phrase</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can replace all `\n` in your textarea with `"\n"` using `replace()`. something like this:

```js
document.getElementById("phraseButton").addEventListener('click', function () {
  var keywordBox = document.getElementById('keywordBox');
   keywordBox.value = ('"' + keywordBox.value + '"');
   keywordBox.value = keywordBox.value.replace(/\n/g, '"\n"')
});
```

```html
<textarea id="keywordBox" type="text" rows="100" cols="30">Insert Keywords</textarea>
<button id="phraseButton">Phrase</button>
```